# Using For and Foreach at the same time (using keys and values in the same loop / breaking after a certain number of steps)

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

```
$numbers = array(1,5,89,2134,123,735,124,...,92492); // totally different numbers..
```

Then...

```
for ($i=0; $i <=30 ; $i++) {}

foreach ($numbers as $num) {
  echo '<p id='.$i.'>Number is  : '.$num.'</p>';
}
```

In here, the `$i` will be the numbers from 0 to 30. 
Basically what i wanna do is, using foreach to create

```
<p></p>
```

with the id upto 30 and each number in the $numbers.

so its gonna be

`<p id="1">Number is: $num[0]</p>
...
...
<p id="30">Number is: $num[lastnumber in array]</p>` .

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: and the question is ??

Comment: So you want to STOP the production of `<p>` tags at 30?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*// Hope I understand the question correctly...*

1. You can have both key and value in the `foreach` loop, using the `as` keyword, like this:

   ```
   foreach ($numbers as $i => $num) {
       echo '<p id=' . $i . '>Number is  : ' . $num . '</p>';
   }
   ```
2. Or you can get the value by the key:

   ```
   for ($i=0; $i <=30 ; $i++) {
       echo '<p id=' . $i . '>Number is  : ' . $numbers[$i] . '</p>';
   }
   ```
3. And if there may be more than 30 array elements but you want to stop at 30, you can either use the solution *2.*, or explicitly break the loop, e.g.

   ```
   $counter = 0;
   foreach ($numbers as $i => $num) {
       echo '<p id=' . $i . '>Number is  : ' . $num . '</p>';
       if (++$counter >= 30) {
           break;
       }
   }
   ```